# Expand and collapse the UITableView row according to UITextView's isScrollEnabled dynamically by clicking the button

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented a UITableView. I have a UITextView and UIButton in table view's cell's content view. Text view's scrolling is enabled and height constraint is given. Table view's row height is automatic depending on text view's height plus button's height.

Now what i want to implement is clicking on button toggle text view's isScrollEnabled property and remove height constraint. On clicking button again toggle text view's isScrollEnabled property and add height constraint.

**In this process the text view is not automatically changing its frame (Similar thing can be achieved by using UILabel in place of UITextView and toggling label's number of lines property instead of text view's is scroll enabled) on button click and thus row height is also not updating.**

Expected result is on first time button click setting text view's isScrollEnabled property to false and removing text view's height constraint will make the text view expand according to text it contains.
On second time button click setting text view's isScrollEnabled property to true and adding text view's height constraint will make the text view collapse to the height constraint's constant value.
And accordingly the table view's row height will also change as I am using autolayout.

Comment: Are you designing your cell via Code or Storyboard Prototype? What is the Height of your text view? And, do you want that to be the "minimum" Height when scrolling is disabled? For example, if your "scrolling" Height is 60, do you want it to still be 60 if there is only one line of text?

Comment: I am using Storyboard for cell design. Initially I have added height constraint to text view with value 64 and scrolling is enabled. On button click I am disabling scrolling and removing height constraint. This should make the text view's height according to the text in it (no minimum height) and due to auto layout the row's height should auto adjust according to text view's new height. But on button click the text view is not changing its height.

Answer (score 1):

A `UITableView` does not automatically recalculate row heights when we dynamically change a cell's height - such as changing a constraint or changing the intrinsic Height of a UI element (e.g. typing in a text view).

So, the cell needs to tell the controller that its content has changed.

Presumably, you're using a protocol/delegate pattern or a closure to update your data when the user types in the text view? If so, that's where we can inform the controller and let it update the row height(s). (*If you're not already doing so, you need to implement that.*)

The easiest way to update the table *without* reloading the data (which we don't want to do) is to call:

```
tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
```

If we're already using a closure to update the data as the user is typing, we can can make that call at the same time... and, we can include the "Expanded / Collapsed" state (so we can track that in our data source) ***and*** we can use the same closure when the user taps the button to toggle scrolling in the text view.

Here's how I have my cell laid-out with its constraints:

[image]

The `Scrolling Height Constraint` is `64`, and it's the constraint we're going to toggle between active / inactive. Note there is a second Height constraint on the text field: `height >= 64`. This keeps the text view at its "minimum height" when being edited. Without that, if we delete enough of the text so we have only one or two lines, instead of this:

[image]

we end up with a cell that looks like this:

[image]

Here is some sample code...

First, a simple struct for our data:

```
struct MyDataItem {
    var text: String = ""
    var isScrollEnabled: Bool = false
}
```

Our cell class will have a closure declared, which we'll use to inform the controller when we have changes:

```
var callback: ((String, Bool) -> ())?
```

Next, an example scroll view controller, that implements that closure in `cellForRowAt`:

```
class ExpandTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var myData: [MyDataItem] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // start with 20 sample strings (so we have table view scrolling)
        for i in 0..<20 {
            myData.append(MyDataItem(text: "Sample string \(i)", isScrollEnabled: true))
        }
        
        // start with 5 lines of text in Second row
        myData[1].text = "Sample string 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4\nLine 5"
        
        // start with long text in Fourth row (for word wrapping)
        myData[3].text = "Sample string 3 - with plenty of text to demonstrate word wrapping in the text view, and how it will affect the scrolling and expand / collapse feature of the cell."
        
        // add a right nav bar "Done" button to stop editing and dismiss the keyboard
        let btn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneTapped))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn
    }
    
    // to dismiss keyboard
    @objc func doneTapped() -> Void {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TextViewCell
        
        let item = myData[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.fillData(item)
        
        cell.callback = { [weak self] str, scroll in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            // update our data
            self.myData[indexPath.row].text = str
            self.myData[indexPath.row].isScrollEnabled = scroll
            
            // tell the table view to re-layout cells where needed
            //  this will change row heights when editing and/or when
            //  tapping Expand/Collapse button
            self.tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Here's the cell class - where most of the "magic" happens :) ... I've included logic to toggle `.isEnabled` on the Expand/Collapse button based on the amount of text in the text view:

```
class TextViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var theTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var theButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet var scrollingHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var callback: ((String, Bool) -> ())?
    
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        
        let t = textView.text ?? ""
        
        // inform the controller that our text changed
        callback?(t, textView.isScrollEnabled)
        
        updateTheButton()

    }
    
    @IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {

        // toggle scrolling on the text view
        theTextView.isScrollEnabled.toggle()

        updateTheConstrints()
        updateTheButton()

        let t = theTextView.text ?? ""

        // inform the controller the expand / collapse button was tapped
        callback?(t, theTextView.isScrollEnabled)

        // if we're editing and just tapped Collapse
        if theTextView.isFirstResponder && theTextView.isScrollEnabled {
            //scroll the text view so the Cursor is visible *after* the view has resized
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.scrollToCursorPosition()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func scrollToCursorPosition() {
        if let r = theTextView.selectedTextRange?.start {
            let c = theTextView.caretRect(for: r)
            theTextView.scrollRectToVisible(c, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    func updateTheButton() -> Void {
        
        // set button title appropriately
        theButton.setTitle(theTextView.isScrollEnabled ? "Expand" : "Collapse", for: [])

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // enable / disablbe button based on amount of text
            //  have to do this async, so it runs after the text has changed
            self.theButton.isEnabled = self.theTextView.contentSize.height > self.scrollingHeightConstraint.constant
        }
        
    }
    
    func updateTheConstrints() -> Void {
        // activate or deactivate text view's height constraint
        scrollingHeightConstraint.isActive = theTextView.isScrollEnabled
    }
    
    func fillData(_ item: MyDataItem) -> Void {
        theTextView.text = item.text
        theTextView.isScrollEnabled = item.isScrollEnabled
        updateTheConstrints()
        updateTheButton()
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        if theTextView != nil {
            // mke sure the text view's delegate is set
            theTextView.delegate = self
            
            // anything else we may want to do on init
        }
    }
}
```

and, finally, the source to the Storyboard I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17156" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="VjW-oA-FRf">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17125"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Expand Table View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="PM6-ph-sPi">
            <objects>
                <tableViewController id="VjW-oA-FRf" customClass="ExpandTableViewController" customModule="DelMe" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" id="xK8-0I-ylV">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <prototypes>
                            <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="textViewCell" rowHeight="101" id="MWI-1y-UOV" customClass="TextViewCell" customModule="DelMe" customModuleProvider="target">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="375" height="101"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="MWI-1y-UOV" id="ZYw-rr-lnO">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="101"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <subviews>
                                        <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet." textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pCr-bW-XWY">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="16" y="11" width="251" height="64"/>
                                            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" constant="64" id="4SV-lM-57L"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="64" id="jBQ-hv-SBY"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                            <color key="textColor" systemColor="labelColor"/>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="16"/>
                                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                                        </textView>
                                        <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Bex-xS-WMG">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="279" y="11" width="80" height="30"/>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="width" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" constant="80" id="CG1-AO-HEE"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                            <state key="normal" title="Expand"/>
                                            <connections>
                                                <action selector="didTap:" destination="MWI-1y-UOV" eventType="touchUpInside" id="KlW-my-Tna"/>
                                            </connections>
                                        </button>
                                    </subviews>
                                    <constraints>
                                        <constraint firstItem="Bex-xS-WMG" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ZYw-rr-lnO" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="3de-fi-JG9"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="pCr-bW-XWY" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ZYw-rr-lnO" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="Xuc-OZ-KQh"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="Bex-xS-WMG" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="ZYw-rr-lnO" secondAttribute="trailingMargin" id="Ypd-BU-eNg"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="Bex-xS-WMG" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="pCr-bW-XWY" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="12" id="ihY-xL-anh"/>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="pCr-bW-XWY" secondAttribute="bottom" id="iu3-Sw-yey"/>
                                        <constraint firstItem="pCr-bW-XWY" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ZYw-rr-lnO" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="o85-kl-ee4"/>
                                    </constraints>
                                </tableViewCellContentView>
                                <connections>
                                    <outlet property="scrollingHeightConstraint" destination="jBQ-hv-SBY" id="AQQ-LK-f5R"/>
                                    <outlet property="theButton" destination="Bex-xS-WMG" id="Dpg-wY-06G"/>
                                    <outlet property="theTextView" destination="pCr-bW-XWY" id="vzw-GP-Eav"/>
                                </connections>
                            </tableViewCell>
                        </prototypes>
                        <connections>
                            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="VjW-oA-FRf" id="g9q-N9-GPB"/>
                            <outlet property="delegate" destination="VjW-oA-FRf" id="9Ff-xj-zPJ"/>
                        </connections>
                    </tableView>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="ztb-ky-WPU"/>
                </tableViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="5rS-VR-5Ht" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-124" y="1613"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="labelColor">
            <color white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Sample output:

[image]